# allow access to the daemon for everyone

Tags: daemon, monerod-commands

I want to make my daemon accessible to anyone, is there an additional command besides this?

```
--confirm-external-bind

--rpc-access-control-origins
```

are there other additions that I have to use?
the example of the daemon I run on my vm with the address `12.325.25.3`

Answer (score 1):

To allow inbound connections to the daemon p2p and the RPC (assuming default ports are used), you would need:

```
--rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0
--confirm-external-bind
```

And ensure your firewall allows inbound connections on ports `18080` and `18081`.

If you are behind a router, that would also need configuring to forward traffic on those ports to your machine running the daemon.

Note, you may also want to add the login option for the RPC:

```
--rpc-login arg                       Specify username[:password] required 
                                      for RPC server
```

And if you want to allow javascript access:

```
--rpc-access-control-origins arg      Specify a comma separated list of 
                                      origins to allow cross origin resource 
                                      sharing
```

Comment: yeah, thanks you, I'm still not clear about this "--rpc-access-control-origins arg" ?                         example --rpc-access-control-origins <my domain> ?

Comment: You only need this is you are allowing a website's javascript code to call RPC methods on the daemon. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin